# POST method of parameters from asp page

Tags: javascript, forms, asp-classic

I have a page with a regular form:

```
<form method="post" action="pro.asp">
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

when it gets to the pro.asp page it will do some server side actions like sending mail and then I need that page to send all the parameters in the post request to another website

I don't want to have another form filled auto and auto submit with javascript script

Is there a solution for that?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean (or how JavaScript is involved).  Is your server-side code creating a POST to the external server?  Or are you trying to direct some client-side code to do that?

Comment: I think you have two pages emails.asp contains some text boxes and you want to submit that information to separate site?? If i am right then javascript will not help. You need to use server side redirection and handling

Comment: Muhammad_Shoaib: but server side redirection will not transfer POST parameters. @david: i want asp page to do post with parameters but to acctually go to that page on the client side (so i can't use xmlhttp for example)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to make a POST to the other website?

The simplest thing to do may be to, when you are finished your own form processing, send the values to the other page as a GET.

To do that all you would need to do is end your processing with a response.redirect.

```
Response.Redirect ("http://somewebsite.com?value=X")
```